# Can't open created .exe file (Racket programming language)

Tags: racket, exe

I converted this code:

```
#lang racket
(require pict3d)
(combine
       (with-color    (rgba "red")
           (sphere   (pos 1 0 0)   1/10) )
       (with-color    (rgba "blue")
           (sphere   (pos 0 1 1)   1/10) )
       (for/list       ( [ t     (in-range   1/10  1  1/10) ] )
           (define  v   (pos-between    (pos 1 0 0)  (pos 0 1 1)  t) )
           (sphere  v  1/20) ) )
```

This code runs successfully. But when i convert this into .exe. It opens interactive Racket(Command Prompt) for a 1 sec. and close it.
I created two exe files with Racket and GRacket. Both don't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run the executable from there.

Comment: Already did it. Output is (object:pict3d% . . .)

Comment: Are you trying to run it on the same machine?

Comment: Yes.  I wanted to send this file to a friend, but when I launched it myself, I canceled sending.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. It creates a 3D object that is returned and it seems the DrRacket IDE has some features for displaying objects that it doesn't in eg. a shell, but when you create an executable you don't get the REPL. You need to make a window with a canvas that paits that object. I'm guessing [rednering docs might be a place to start](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict3d/rendering.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pict3d%2Fmain..rkt%29._pict3d-canvas~25%29%29)